# Wrap <pre></pre> into custom background in android WebView

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I am working on a project that includes a **webview** to show html in it.

My question is, how I can wrap

```
 tagged text into custom background.
```

Heres a example text in pre tag

`<pre>
Welcome to my app, hope you will enjoy
</pre>`

But every time I only get text, I want add a background behind the text.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you can use CSS for that.

Comment: How I cam use CSS to wrap it?

Comment: how about some searching? https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=css+background+color+pre&oq=css+background+color+pre&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.9255j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can maybe help you: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp
Normally they wrap it around the the tag `<body>`. 
You need to do this then:
`body {
    background-image: url("paper.gif");
}`